# GET method in java web service via netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans, get

i'm currently creating a java web service via Netbeans.
I'm deploying the web service to a Tomcat 7.
I'm able to call the web service via the POST method but i'd like to use GET as well.
I have no idea how to make GET work.  Is it a config issue with tomcat, do i need to add specific code in the web service, ...?

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying "web services" you mean SOAP, right? Or may be REST?
SOAP web services over HTTP can only use POST, since the POST body contains the SOAP Request, while GET request cannot contain body.

Comment: i'm relatively new to web services so i'm not sure that it's soap that netbeans sets up. but at least that might explain why get isn't working

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans will create SOAP based webservice by default , unless you ask for RESTFULL webservices. You cannot call a SOAP webservice via GET.

Answer (score 0):

you need to request webservice url as normal in java, but first you must make webservice to run with get method by adding in web.config under  **system.web**

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

then request your webservice and send paramters in querysting normally.